# iTunes store purchased media items: usability in another country?

Tags: appletv, itunes-store, streaming

An Apple account with a Canadian billing address and payment method is used to buy movies on the Canadian iTunes store. Will an Apple TV 4k located physically in another country (say, Vietnam) be able to stream these movies if it is logged in with this same account? (The account's payment and address remain Canadian.)

Answer (score 1):

welcome to AskDifferent. I can't tell you if it works in your specific combination. Normally Apple does not restrict content via Geolocation blocking. I'm able to download and watch all Content (Music, Movies, TV-Shows and also Apps) in Germany and USA. I have an austrian Store Account.

Does this example of mine help you?

Comment: It's a positive signal so it does! +1